# How stop overwrite input value from v-model in vueJs?

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

it's possible to stop overwriting input value from v-model when I use php value

Code:

```
<div id="app" class="padding3">
  <input type="text" name="" value="Value From PHP Important" v-model="checkIfNotEmpty">

  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" @click="disableButton=false" :disabled="disableButton">Save</button>
</div>
```

[codepen example](http://codepen.io/lado-bortishvili/pen/LrVboY?editors=1111)

Comment: here's a codepen showing the issue https://codepen.io/CSWApps/pen/RQbvvp

Comment: If you don't want the value to be overwritten by the user, just disable the input field.

Comment: no i want to display value="Value From PHP Important" and i can't do that. because when i use v-model it hide this value 'Value From PHP Important'